# Google Sheets - Google app scripts - way to get full sheet data plus styling

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get all sheet values, functions and stylings etc in one call to Google?

The only way I have found to do it is to call each style separately for the active range.

If possible i'd like to get all data/formulas/styling etc for the sheet in one go.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
var backgrounds = activeRange.getBackgrounds();
var fontSizes = activeRange.getFontSizes();
var colours = activeRange.getFontColors();
var alignments = activeRange.getHorizontalAlignments();  
var values = activeRange.getValues();
var formulas = activeRange.getFormulas();
var vAlignments = activeRange.getVerticalAlignments();
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it?  You can copy a range and it will copy everything.

Comment: I want to pass it up to a sidebar, but I want get everything, thanks i'll try copying a range and see what that gives me

Comment: "pass it up to a sidebar"? I don't understand.  Sidebar is html.  If you need to know the alignment, color, etc then you would need to get each of those attributes as you have done.  Loop through each and decifer the attribute value to set the html element attribute.

Comment: Ok - I really just wanted to get the full sheet in say JSON format that I could parse out the bits I wanted.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch full spreadsheet data using the [Advanced Sheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) as follows:

```
var ssID = "[YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID]";
var fields = "developerMetadata,namedRanges,properties,sheets,spreadsheetId,spreadsheetUrl";

var fullSpreadsheetData = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {"fields":fields});
```

The call to `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(...)` returns a [Spreadsheet Resource object](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet) as defined by the Sheets API.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I am after!

Comment: @user3284707 There are a few caveats, you won't get embedded images nor any scripts bound to the spreadsheet.

Comment: That's fine i'm really only after the data.  Do you know of a way to get just the active sheets data, the issue is that it's still a bit slow to get everything, I was hoping it may be quicker if I just get the active sheet?

Comment: @user3284707 None that I know of. The best you can do is edit the `fields` parameter to limit the properties being sent. You can experiment with the fields editor via [Google's API Explorer for the `sheets.spreadsheets.get` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get) to find an optimal property set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your end goals are here, but you would always use the copyTo() method from the sheet class..

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID_GOES HERE');
sheet.copyTo(destination);
```

That will give you an exact copy of your sheet with all the formatting and data intact.  The 'Sheet' object that you are returned when you call `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` does contain all the data/formulas/styling, so in a way, the answer is yes.  You can get it all with one call.  Unfortunately, to use that data you have to use the individual methods contained in the 'Sheet' object that you already have listed.  If it is just a copy of the sheet you need, I also dig the `insertSheet()` method which is part of the 'Spreadsheet' class.  That would look like this..

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sales');
ss.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});
```

If neither one of those methods work for you, maybe including what your intentions are in the question will help the community find you an answer.

Comment: I really wanted the sheet in a JSON format which had all the properties I wanted, I want to replicate some of the sheet on the side bar including all formatting row width height etc, so I wanted a quick way to get the full sheet which I could then parse and process on the client side.  There are some calls to Google like row width and height which cannot be done in bulk as far as I can see and they are taking a while to process iterating over each cell in the change